# Laravel / Composer - Does "composer dump-autoload" restart Apache?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

After you make changes to the `routes.php` file in Laravel, you need to run `composer dump-autoload` for the changes to take effect.  If you're not using Laravel and you make edits to the `.htaccess` file, you need to restart your Apache server for any routing changes to take place.

If this is the case, does `composer dump-autoload` restart Apache?

Comment: No, `composer dump-autoload` will not restart Apache. It will simply regenerate your `autoload` file.

Comment: I'm not actually sure that you *do* need to run `composer dump-autoload` for changes in routes.php to take effect, *or* that you need to restart apache to pick up changes to `.htaccess` files. Do you have any evidence for either? (Also, routes.php and .htaccess use completely different methods to do their work, so I'm not sure what the connection would be, anyway...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infact, composer dumpautoload is used when you've added new files / classes. Like, when you've added a migration and want to do a migration:rollback.

When you update the routes file and save it, it works instantly. Same with .htaccess changes.

The only time when you need to restart apache is when you've changed php.ini or added modules etc.

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer: It does not restart apache. You need to run it when you define new class or change their path etc. so when you say `After you make changes to the routes.php file in Laravel` then you are wrong. it sgould be `After you create a new class or change their path or anything that needs to be included in autoload_classmap.php`

Some info on it:

It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project. Composer is a major part of the Laravel MVC Framework, but it also exists without Laravel. In fact you could use it in any project.In laravel it does:

1) It will in fact use Composer for some stuff

2) It will call Composer with the optimize flag

3) It will 'recompile' loads of files creating the huge bootstrap/compiled.php

4) And also will find all of your Workbench packages and composer dump-autoload them, one by one.